# ORACLE - How to JOIN in this situation [other option other than JOIN]?

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got the following query in Oracle

```
select (case when seqnum = 1 then id else '0' end) as id,
       (case when seqnum = 1 then start else "end" end) as timestamp,
       unit
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id, unit order by start) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by id, unit) as cnt
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1 or seqnum = cnt;
```

instead of selecting unit, which is a number, I want to bring its description. The description is stored in another table, and I'm trying to bring the desciption instead of the number.

```
SELECT t2.unit_description from t2,t where t2.unit = t.unit
```

I'm trying to JOIN these results but it's not working. Can anyone help me in this situation?

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working" ? Could you please add example input data and expected output?

Comment: Thanks guys I was trying to add t2.unit = t.unit in the WHERE clause that's why it was not working. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
select (case when t.seqnum = 1 then t.id else '0' end) as id,
       (case when t.seqnum = 1 then t.start else t."end" end) as timestamp,
       t.unit,
       t2.unit_description
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id, unit order by start) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by id, unit) as cnt
      from table t 
     ) t join
     t2
     on t2.unit = t.unit
where seqnum = 1 or seqnum = cnt;
```

Answer (score 2):

Does this not work?

```
select (case when seqnum = 1 then id else '0' end) as id,
       (case when seqnum = 1 then start else "end" end) as timestamp,
       t2.unit_description
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id, unit order by start) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by id, unit) as cnt
      from table t
     ) t
join t2 on t.unit = t2.unit
where seqnum = 1 or seqnum = cnt;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select (case when seqnum = 1 then id    else 0     end)             as id,
       (case when seqnum = 1 then start else "end" end)             as timestamp,
       (SELECT t2.unit_description from t2 where t2.unit = t.unit)  as unit
  from (select t.*,
               row_number() over (partition by id, unit order by start) as seqnum,
               count(*) over (partition by id, unit) as cnt
          from table t
        ) t
  where seqnum = 1 or seqnum = cnt;
```